# Fiddler with Android Emulator mostly shows "A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found" with no headers or data

Tags: windows, android, sniffer, fiddler

When I run fiddler with a proxy for the BlueStacks Android emulator (on Windows), many of the results are listed as "Tunnel to" a random IP address, with no headers and no information on the data sent. Clicking on one reveals "A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below." but nothing else that I can decipher.

I have HTTPS capture and decrypt on, and it works for a few API calls from this app, but the majority are shown as the IP addresses explained above.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix it so that I can see information on these.

Comment: This is just a guess, but: do you maybe need to install the Fiddler root cert within the emulated Android environment? I don't know how BlueStacks works but if it's depending on its own root CAs rather that the OS root CA store (or if you haven't installed the Fiddler root CA anywhere), that would cause this problem.

Comment: What you describe is the common behavior when the Fiddler root CA certificate is not trusted. You need to install the Fiddler root CA certificate into the BlueStacks emulator as system certificate.